# The audio doesn't work

Tags: sound, headphones

The audio doesn't work. Even if I connect headphones they don't work.
I tried various things but none worked. I just can't hear anything.

Comment: Can you hear the audio if you run an Ubuntu live session from the live USB that you used to install Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know. I have deleted ubuntu from the usb, once I installed it.